# Control File for SQL LOADER

Tags: sql, oracle, extensible

Hi I have a problem with importing data into multiple tables. Anybody can help me with writing to the control file that import from CSV into multiple tables.

lets say I want column 1,2,3 from EXCEL CSV into table employee and table 4,5,7 into table employee_info.

Please help me

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005798